# DOM manipulation with Kotlin Javascript in Eclipse Maven project

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven, kotlin

I have a Kotlin Javascript Maven project in Eclipse with the following pom.xml:

```
<project>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-js</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.51</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                ...
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        ...
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It works if I do a normal `println("Hello World!")` message.
But I'm not able to run the following code:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and Gradle, not Eclipse and Maven, so I can not tell you what's the problem here. But I can confirm that your Kotlin code is perfectly valid. It seems to be a problem with the project setup, since the browser package can not be imported.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the reference returned by `getElementById` might be `null`. As Kotlin tries to avoid the danger of null references, you have to explicitly handle this situation yourself. You can read more about this and about your options in the [Kotlin Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

The "Java way" here would be

```
document.getElementById(listName)!!.innerHTML = "Test"
```

as this throws a `NullPointerException` if the returned reference is `null` or set the `innerHTML` otherwise.